# Как передать еще один параметр в контроллер?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться, есть следующий код контроллера

```
[GET]
public async Task<ContentResult> Auction([FromQuery(Name = "ids")] int[] ids, AuctionModel auctionModel)
{
    var partners = _AdCampaignMsSqlBl.GetRtbPartners(ids);
    var result = await _rtbService.GetAuctionResult(partners.Values, auctionModel);

    return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = result,
        ContentType = "application/xml",
        StatusCode = 200
    };
}
```

В данном случаи в него передается массив `ids` и через `ModelBinder` заполняется моделька `auctionModel`, но сейчас необходимо передать еще один параметр типа `string` который будет содержать значения разделенные дефисом (например `5-5-5`), как можно его добавить?

P.S.
Пробовал так, но строка все равно отставалось пустой (`null`)

```
[GET]
public async Task<ContentResult> Auction([FromQuery(Name = "ids")] int[] ids, AuctionModel auctionModel, string platfrom)
{
}
```

```
[GET]
public async Task<ContentResult> Auction([FromQuery(Name = "ids")] int[] ids, [FromQuery(Name = "platfrom")]string platfrom, AuctionModel auctionModel)
{
}
```

Comment: Как именно хотите передать? `[FromQuery` - значит, что параметр будет в строке url.

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался